# Фризы при скролле текста

Tags: java, android

Есть ScrollView с TextView внутри. На слабых и средних устройствах, при большом тексте начинаются лаги при скролле. Возможно ли как-то оптимизировать текст, чтобы он не лагал?

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@id/scrollView"
    android:layout_height="150.0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:layout_width="400dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="15"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: А без `ScrollView` пробовали? `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` для `TextView` пропишите вместо скролла.

Comment: @Suvitruf Прописал. Теперь почему-то вообще не скроллится.

Comment: @Suvitruf Такие же лаги.